# Dask tutorial failing with distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker

Tags: client, dask, restart

Interested in the possibilities offered by Dask, I started with [the dask tutorial](https://tutorial.dask.org/00_overview.html), and prepared my laptop by following the instructions as per the tutorial: cloning the repo and making a new conda env with:

```
conda env create -f binder/environment.yml
conda activate dask-tutorial
```

All goes fine and packages are installed. Then i kickoff jupyter lab and open the first workbook:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client()
```

The output is an almost-infinite printing of "distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker", some followed by more errors (see below). I spent the last couple of hours trying to figure out why I'm having this problem, but I don't find.
Tried bringing a LocalCluster(), it didn't help. Tried limiting the memory to 1GB, same problem.
Tried updating the packages, rebooting the laptop, still nothing.

Note, if that can be useful: I'm on Windows, I use conda, and this is a company laptop on which I don't have the admin rights.

Would anyone know why i have this issue?

Thanks!
Emek

P.S: Amongst the plethora of "distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker", I also get a few:

```
2023-02-10 16:04:36,283 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
2023-02-10 16:04:36,408 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
2023-02-10 16:04:36,425 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\envs\dask-tutorial\lib\site-packages\distributed\nanny.py", line 853, in _wait_until_connected
    msg = self.init_result_q.get_nowait()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\envs\dask-tutorial\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 135, in get_nowait
    return self.get(False)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\envs\dask-tutorial\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 116, in get
    raise Empty
_queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\envs\dask-tutorial\lib\site-packages\distributed\utils.py", line 741, in wrapper
    return await func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\envs\dask-tutorial\lib\site-packages\distributed\nanny.py", line 545, in _on_worker_exit
    await self.instantiate()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\envs\dask-tutorial\lib\site-packages\distributed\nanny.py", line 442, in instantiate
    result = await self.process.start()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\envs\dask-tutorial\lib\site-packages\distributed\nanny.py", line 714, in start
    msg = await self._wait_until_connected(uid)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\envs\dask-tutorial\lib\site-packages\distributed\nanny.py", line 855, in _wait_until_connected
    await asyncio.sleep(self._init_msg_interval)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\envs\dask-tutorial\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 605, in sleep
    return await future
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
2023-02-10 16:04:37,021 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
2023-02-10 16:04:37,024 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
2023-02-10 16:04:37,027 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
```

Comment: You should put the `client = Client()` within a `if __name__=="__main__":` call. See [here](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/516#issuecomment-306468605) for more details

Comment: @RehanRajput the op says they’re using a notebook so this likely isn’t the culprit as far as I can tell. To me this seems like an environment issue. Anaconda and conda-forge don’t mix well so this could be the culprit….

Comment: I confirm that this on Jupyter lab. I have tried creating a new environment but still the same issue. `conda create -n dask2 -c conda-forge python dask dask-labextension jupyterlab`.
I think [this issue](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/7536) depicts the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Followed [this answer](https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyter_server/issues/1198#issuecomment-1426934230) suggesting to downgrade ipykernel and it solved the issue for now.

```
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  ipykernel                             6.21.1-pyh025b116_0 --> 6.15.0-pyh025b116_0
```

Comment: I got this error when trying to downgrade: 
`WARNING: The candidate selected for download or install is a yanked version: 'ipykernel' candidate (version 6.21.0 at https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/60/6a1ad6f31447936c70f641fe07e3e8cde9e3f74839419f32538277139082/ipykernel-6.21.0-py3-none-any.whl (from https://pypi.org/simple/ipykernel/) (requires-python:>=3.8))
Reason for being yanked: tk backend broke`